# JPA Query returns no result

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am trying to search for some entities of kind "Book" in datastore using codes below.But it is returning empty List.I get a empty result list with size=-1.Where am I getting wrong?

```
@ApiMethod(name = "searchBook")
public List<Book> searchBook(@Named("bookName") String bookName,@Named("languageId")String languageId, @Named("subjectId")String subjectId) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    List<Book> bookList=new ArrayList<Book>();
    String queryString="";

    queryString="SELECT x FROM Book x WHERE ";

   //If i dont want to set any parameter for some field, I send BLANK as the parameter..
    if(bookName!=null && !bookName.matches("BLANK")){
        queryString=queryString+"x.bookName =:bookName"+" AND ";
    }
    if(languageId!=null && !languageId.matches("BLANK")){
        queryString=queryString+"x.languageId =:languageId"+" AND ";

    }

    if(subjectId!=null && !subjectId.matches("BLANK")){
        queryString=queryString+"x.categoryId =:subjectId"+" AND ";

    }

    //Removing last word "AND" and whitespaces from the end of queryString
    queryString=queryString.substring(0,queryString.length()-5);
    Query q = mgr.createQuery(queryString);

    //setting query parameters..
    if(bookName!=null && !bookName.matches("BLANK")){
        q.setParameter("bookName", bookName);

    }
    if(languageId!=null && !languageId.matches("BLANK")){
        q.setParameter("languageId", languageId);
    }

    if(subjectId!=null && !subjectId.matches("BLANK")){
        q.setParameter("subjectId", subjectId);
    }

    //executing the query...
    try {
            mgr.getTransaction().begin();
            bookList = (List<Book>) q.getResultList();
            mgr.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        mgr.close();
    }

    return bookList;
}
```

In my case I have tested by setting only one parameter for subjectId. Is something wrong in setting parameters? Is this the correct way to set dynamic number of parameters in a query?

Comment: looking in the log is the way things are debugged

Comment: @NeilStockton will you please elaborate how?Any relevant link? I am using eclipse IDE.

Comment: you should see part of your logs in eclipse's console.  If you pushed it to appengine, just go to "yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/admin"  and it'll give you your project's admin console, where you can click on "logs"

Comment: The log should be viewed at DEBUG level, to see what is happening, queries sent to GAE/Datastore etc. Any GAE docs should have a page for where you see the log.

Comment: @Julidar,@Neil Is that the proper way I am creating a querystring and query when I have to set variable number of parameters at runtime. Or there are better ways?I have posted a new question here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409466/dynamic-number-of-parameters-for-a-jpa-query/25409568#25409568